# ¿Como puedo crear una libreria de clase Net Core en Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, vscode

Mi Computadora es un poco obsoleta y usar Visual Studio Comunity es algo imposible para mi.

Por eso quiero cambiar a vs code, mucho mas ligero y consume menos recursos.
Pero tengo un problema cuando creo una libreria de clase, este me crea una (libreria de clase estandar).

No sé como darle la opcion al vs code para que me cree una Libreria de clases Net Core

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver, no me dice nada de libreria de clases Net Core, solo Estandar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una libreria que usa `.net standard` esta usando `.net core`

No se si lesite la documentacion al respecto

[.NET Standard](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/net-standard)

pero si lo haces veras que al usar una version de `.net standard` estas teniendo compatibilidad sobre varias plataformas, ya que tiene compatibilidad con diferentes versiones de .net

En tu caso menciona `net standard 2`, en el articulo aun no se actualizo, pero quizas aqui si lo encuentren

[Introducing .NET Standard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/)

debes buscar en el cuadro con cuales versiones es compatible

Comment: muchas gracias por responder, no lo sabia, dejame leer la documentacion.